# Firestore updating 2 different documents

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore in my app and have 2 collections `Customers` and `Properties`. I have an activity where the user can update the data contained in a customer document name address etc. This code shown below is working fine.

```
db.collection("Customers").document(customer.getCustomerId())
                .update(
                        "name", c.getName(),
                        "email", c.getEmail(),
                        "phoneNo", c.getPhoneNo(),
                        "address", c.getAddress(),
                        "creatorId", c.getCreatorId()
                )
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
```

I have the document reference of the customers saved in the Properties documents so I can reference which customer owns which property. Using this reference I want to search for Properties containing that reference and update the name field if it has been changed. I have tried adding the code into my method after the onComplete checks for the above code, but it doesn't update the name field every time only every few attempts.

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference propRef = rootRef.collection("Properties");
        propRef.whereEqualTo("customerId", customerId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                        Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("customer", customerName);
                        propRef.document(document.getId()).set(map, SetOptions.merge()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do? 
I did think I could do it using batch but from what I have read this does not allow searching.

@AlexMamo

This is a document from my Customers collection

[image: document from my Customers collection]

This is a linked document from my Properties collection

[image: a linked document from my Properties collection]

Customers Structure

[image: Customers Structure]

Properties Structure

[image: Properties Structure]

Comment: "I could do it using batch but from what I have read this does not allow searching." wait what ? A batched writes is just a set of write operations and if you want to update multiple documents at the same time and to deal with data consistency, you can run a batch.

Comment: I could not work out how to search for the matching Properties documents and assign the changes within the batched writes

Comment: Please add your database structure for both collections and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added 2 screenshots of a customer and the linked property entry

Comment: I cannot see any document reference in your property object. What reference are you talking about, a `DocumentReference`? Can you please explain what is the query that you want to perform first and based on that what is the secode one? And what is expected result according to your examples?

Comment: @AlexMamo Sorry I have it stored in the customerId field. That value is the DocumentReference for the attached customer. What I am trying to achieve is If the user performs an update to the customer document I want to get the new name value from the customer and update the Properties customer field

Comment: Update the Properties customer field with what? I cannot see a name property in your property document. I only see `address`, `bathrooms`, `bedrooms` and so on.

Comment: @AlexMamo So at the moment the above Customers document has a field - name "Bobb Geldoff" and the Properties document has a field - customer "Bobb Geldoff". if the user changes the Customers document field - name to "Bobby Geldoff" I want to also change the Properties document field - customer to "Bobby Geldoff" so that it still holds the same string

Comment: I understand now. In this case, please provide the entire structure (collections, documents) for your both type of documents.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added that above

Comment: Ok, I see more clear mow. I'll write you an anwer.

Comment: Please see my answer below and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, to solve your the issue, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference propertiesRef = rootRef.collection("Properties");
CollectionReference customersRef = rootRef.collection("Customers");
customersRef.whereEqualTo("customerId", customerId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                String customerName = document.getString("name");
                propertiesRef.whereEqualTo("customerId", customerId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                                propertiesRef.document(doc.getId()).update("customer", customerName);       
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See you should use different `CollectionReference` objects, `propertiesRef` and `customersRef`, you are using a single one.

Comment: Thanks this was just what I needed after swapping the reference calls around works perfectly thankyou

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement the Interface from firestore OnDataChange and receive the new values of your variables bind to your views.

in that case when you modify or update a value in your firestore the change triggers this interface and you can assign the new change.

```
ValueEventListener myListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Customer customer = dataSnapshot.getValue(Customer.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
rootRef.addValueEventListener(myListener);
```

hopefully it works for you.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?authuser=0

Comment: Thanks so I can use onDataChange to update the matching Properties documents if a Customer document is updated?